# I have a problem in sum odd numbers in an array using if -else inside for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, sum

I wrote a program to enter ten numbers and sum the odd and even seperately, it is all going good with summing the even, but when it come to odd numbers it gives other value...

I tried different for loop for even and odd, it is also give another value..

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int i, a[10];
 int Even_Sum = 0, Odd_Sum = 0;




 for(i =1; i <=10; i++)
 {
      printf("Insert number %d: ",i);
      scanf("%d", &a[i]);
 }

 for(i = 1; i <=10; i ++)
 {
   if(a[i] % 2 == 0)
   {
    Even_Sum = Even_Sum + a[i];
   }
   else
   {
    Odd_Sum = Odd_Sum + a[i];
   }
 }

 printf("\n The Sum of Even Numbers in this Array = %d ", Even_Sum);
 printf("\n The Sum of Odd Numbers in this Array = %d ", Odd_Sum);
 return 0;
}
```

the inputs are : 
2 3 5 4 6 12 3 7 4 9

what i expect for output will be :

```
The Sum of Even Numbers in this Array = 28
The Sum of Odd Numbers in this Array = 27
```

Comment: Don't forget that array indexes are *zero* based. That is, an array of ten element will have valid indexes from `0` to `9` (inclusive).

Comment: Try `for(i =0; i < 10; i++)` and see, if you get the expected output. Btw: Always check the return value of `scanf()` to see, if the conversion succeeded and handle faulty input appropriately.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, by default output to the stream `stdout` (which is what `printf` writes to) is *line buffered*. That means the buffer is flushed and actually written to the terminal when there's a newline. By printing leading newlines you flush the *previous* line. The current line will not actually be written to the terminal, so depending the code the output might not seem to be displayed. And it will make the last output of the program run together with the prompt of the command-line shell. So I recommend you use *trailing* newlines instead.

Comment: So, how to get a reverse order for the array ?

Comment: To iterate over an array in reverse, think a little bit about the `for` loop... Right now you start at the lowest index and iterate to the highest index. How would you reverse that? And if you have problems with it, that's the subject of another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array always begin with 0; hence your range should be 0 to 9.

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
      printf("Insert number %d: ",i);
      scanf("%d", &a[i]);
 }

 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
   if(a[i] % 2 == 0)
   {
    Even_Sum = Even_Sum + a[i];
   }
   else
   {
    Odd_Sum = Odd_Sum + a[i];
   }
 }
```